# Java : Protected access restriction for subclass on superclass object

Tags: java

I know that this has been asked before in this forum but i will ask again since i don't see any good answer (so far).

Here it goes:

```
package a;
public class A{
    protected int a;
}

package b;
public class B extends A{
}

package c;
public class C extends B｛
    public void accessField(){
        A ancient = new A();
        ancient.a = 2;  //A - That wouldn't work.

        a = 2;   //B - That works.
    }

｝
```

Why clause A) won't work? What's the rational behind this restriction on superclass object ancient access in subclass C?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess one inheritance step here is redundant to illustrate the case.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I guess the question is more theoretical than practical but not uninteresting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Protected members can only be accessed outside of the same package if it's via inheritance - i.e. within the hierarchy.

So when you're creating another instance of A from a different package, that's not an inheritance relationship and it thus fails.

As always, this is covered in the JLS, 6.6.2:

> A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object.

Comment: I am confused. The same section also says "*Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.*" - it does not say *direct* subclass, just subclass...

Comment: @assylias Fair point - that's not what I meant by direct in this instance, but I see how it could be ambiguous so I've changed the wording slightly!

Answer (score 5):

Actually you don't need two levels of inheritance and the code below would lead to the same behaviour:

```
public class B extends A{
     public void accessField() {
        A ancient = new A();
        ancient.a = 2;  //A - That wouldn't work.

        a = 2;   //B - That works.
    }
}
```

The reason why `a = 2` works is [JLS 6.2.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.1):

> Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.

Note that it does not say *direct* subclass, but only subclass. So `a = 2` works within the `B` class or the `C` class.

On the other hand, `ancient.a = 2;` is covered by the next bullet point in the same section:

> If the access is by a qualified name Q.Id, where Q is an ExpressionName, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of the expression Q is S or a subclass of S.

In your case, `Q.Id` is `ancient.a` => it would only be accessible if the type of `ancient` was `B` or a subclass of `B`. So for example, this would compile:

```
public class B extends A{
     public void accessField() {
        C ancient = new C();
        ancient.a = 2;  //A - That wouldn't work.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from book The Java Programming Language 3 ed. by Gosling et all - page 81  sec 3.5

**"What Protected really means"**  - .. beyond being accessible within the class itself and to code within the same package , a protected member can also be accessed from a class through object references that are of *atleast the same type as the class* - that is references of class's type or one of its subclass

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [JLS 6.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2)

*A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object.*

When you say,

```
A ancient = new A();
ancient.a = 2;
```

you are not inheriting anything from ancient (A object) and thus not responsible for its implementation. By making *C extends A*, you have already inherited 'a' from a different A object, hence the statement below works.

```
a = 2;
```

If,

```
ancient.a = 2;
```

works, then there is not difference between a public and a private access specifier.