# Accessing protected members outside package with child class reference

Tags: java, protected, access-modifiers

```
package pack1;
class A{
   protected void m1(){
      System.out.println("protected modifier");
   }
}

package pack2;
class B extends A{
    public static void main(string[]args){
         B b = new B();//Valid
         b.m1();

        A a = new B();//Invalid
          a.m2();

       A a1 = new A();//InValid
         a1.m1();

   }
}
```

Why while accessing protected members outside package we need to have child class reference only.?

Why we cant use parent reference to access protected members (Here A a = new B())?

I have gone through blogs and many stack overflow answers but didn't find any answer for WHY?.

so can anyone help me knowing the answer for WHY?

Comment: You are not allowed to access `A` because you are still **outside** of a subclass or package. The `main` method is `static`, thus unbound from instances of the `B` class. In order to access `A` you need to be *inside* the `B` class, so in a non-static context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java : Protected access restriction for subclass on superclass object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799709/java-protected-access-restriction-for-subclass-on-superclass-object)

Comment: @Zabuza  can you please elaborate your answer?,to me its still not clear

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to access `A` because you are still **outside** of a subclass or package. The `main` method is `static`, thus unbound from instances of the `B` class. In order to access `A` you need to be *inside* the `B` class, so in a non-static context like

```
public class B extends A {
    public void foo() {
        m1(); // Valid call since inside subclass
    }
}
```

I think you have misunderstood what `static` means.

---

The details of `protected` are described in the **Java Language Specification**. Extract from [JLS§6.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2):

> A `protected` member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is **responsible for the implementation** of that object.
>
> Let `C` be the class in which a `protected` member is declared. Access is **permitted only within the body** of a subclass `S` of `C`.

The limitation even goes beyond your example. The key is "*responsible for the implementation*". Compare that to the following example:

```
package a;

public class Point {
    protected int x;
    protected int y;
}
```

```
package b;

import a.Point;

public class Point3D extends Point {
    public void delta(Point other) {
        other.x += this.x;  // Compile-time error: Cannot access other.x
        other.y += this.y;  // Compile-time error: Cannot access other.y
    }
}
```

Though the class `Point3D` is a subclass of `Point`, it is not responsible for the implementation of the `other` object. Thus, it is not allowed to access its `protected` members.

Same for

```
public class B extends A {
    public void foo() {
        A other = new A();
        other.m1(); // Compile-time error
    }
}
```

since the current instance to which the `foo()` method call belongs to is not responsible for the implementation of `other`. Thus, access is not permitted.

Comment: That's just wrong. Your last call `new A().m1();` is invalid, and gives you an error: `The method m1() from the type A is not visible`. You are *not* allowed to access protected method `A.m1()` from B unless you are calling it on an instance of type `B`. You cannot call it on `new A().m1()` from inside `B`, no matter whether you are in a static context or not.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt That is correct. For the exact same reason than the last example. The key is "*responsible for the implementation*" as stated in the JLS paragraph.

Comment: @Zabuza, "Point3D is a subclass of Point, it is not responsible for the implementation of the  p object"..if Point3D is not responsible for providing implementation then who is responsible according to you?

Comment: @sainathpawar It's about the current instance of `Point3D`. Not the class itself. Imagine you have a class `Person`, then you can have multiple instances like `john` and `jane`. And the `john` instance is not responsible for `jane`s stuff. Thus, he is not allowed to access `jane`s `protected` members. Only `jane` is allowed to do that. And `john` is only responsible for his own `protected` members, so he can only access them.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of inheritance/polymorphism makes the inherited public and protected methods and variables of the parent class - members of the child class and is therefore accessible to the objects of the child class. protected access requires two rules-

1. can only be accessed by classes that are within the same package
2. can be accessed via inheritance.

   A a = new B();

   a.m1(); //doesn't compile

This is an instance of the B class but as far as it is a reference of A, it is an A object. That is why the object "a" only has access to members that are common to A and B. i.e object "a" as a reference of class A has access only to the inherited methods of class B. It does not have access to any method or class variable of B that is absent in A even though it is an instance of class B. You have to explicitly cast it to a B to give it access to unique methods & variables of class B. So, bearing this in mind, as far as Java is concerned, object "a" is a class A object that is in another package. Therefore even though the method a.m1 was inherited, "a" does not have access to it because it is an A object in another package. a.m1 will compile in pack1.

Contrast that with this code

```
B b = new B();
b.m1() //compiles
```

b is an object of B and therefore rule 2 of the protected access applies. Since m1 is an inherited protected method of the object B, it has full access to it.